# Get values of an object of dictionary array of object value " Dictionary<string, object[]>"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm looking to deserialize a json object, and I in my json class, I have an attribute of type `Dictionary<string, Name[]>`.

How could I access `Names` attributes after deserializing my json data?

Json

```
{
    "cache": [ {
        "data": {
            "names": {
                "1": [{
                    "firstname": "John",
                    "secondname": "Doe"
                }],
                "2": [{
                     "firstname": "Alice",
                    "secondname": "Smith"
                }],
                "3": [{
                     "firstname": "John",
                    "secondname": "John"
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Json class

```
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using Sample;
//
//    var jsonRoot = JsonRoot.FromJson(jsonString);
namespace Sample
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class JsonRoot
    {
        [JsonProperty("cache")]
        public Cache[] Cache { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Cache
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("names")]
        public Dictionary<string, Name[]> Names { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Name
    {
        [JsonProperty("firstname")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("secondname")]
        public string Secondname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `obj.Cache.Data.Names`

Comment: @viveknuna Cache is an array... you would need to use an index for it.

Comment: I just gave him hint to proceed @Jawad

Comment: Note:  What you have are **properties** and *not* "attributes". An "attribute" in .NET is an entirely different thing. As an aside I've been seeing an increasing number of new users use this incorrect terminology, as if there's some new text book or course promoting their usage. I really wish we could nip this in the bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to print the Key and FirstName

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRoot>(json);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Name[]> name in obj.Cache.FirstOrDefault().Data.Names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name.Key + " " + name.Value.First().Firstname);
}
```

Your cache is an array, you can find a way to iterate through each of those.. for this example, i used `FirstOrDefault()`.

In the foreach loop, I am printing the first element of each `Name[]` since thats all you have in the json example, but you can elaborate the method by iterating through each of the `Name` object if there are more.

```
// Prints
1 John
2 Alice
3 John
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required values in the below manner.

```
JsonRoot root = ......;
var values = root.Cache.Select(x => x.Data).Select(y => y.Names);
foreach( var dictionary in values)
{
    var keys = dictionary.Keys;

    foreach(string key in keys)
    {
        Name[] names = dictionary[key];
    }
}
```

Please handle the `null` cases.